# JavaScript is not making call to controller

Tags: javascript, json, spring-mvc

java script is not making call to my controller Why?? whats wrong with my code ..plz help
java Script and controller code is as following.....`enter code here`

```js
<script>
function tmp()
{ 
 //alert("gg");
 $.ajax({
  type :"POST",
  url :"myController.html",
  data:{message:"hii"},
  dataType :"JSON",
  async : false,  
  success:function(jArray){
   alert("message sent"+jArray[0]["name"]);},
  error:function(e){
   alert("faild");
   }
  });
}
</script>
```

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/myController",method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String view(HttpServletRequest request) {
    System.out.println("*****************************************");

    JsonArray array = new JsonArray();
    JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
    jsonObject.addProperty("name", "Abc");
    array.add(jsonObject);
    return new Gson().toJson(array);
}
```

Comment: alert is working fine but controller is not working

Comment: check your URL  it should be myController only remove .html

Comment: i tried that too ...problem remains unresolved

Comment: whats error you are getting check your network tab in browser.

Comment: no error on browser,consol ...am using STS(Spring tool suit)

Comment: How are you calling tmp()?

Comment: <input type="text" id="name" name="name " onfocus="tmp()" placeholder="HIIII"/>